# How can I import a DLL function which returns this structure?

Tags: c#, visual-c++, dllimport

I have a DLL and its header file, which were written in Visual C++. I need to use the following function in a C# project:

```
LIBSPEC int
CprFindDevices(
  PCprDeviceInfo *ppDevInfo,
  int *pNumDevices,
  DWORD timeout
  );
```

I am able to import it with a `DllImport`, but I cannot figure out how to implement the following structure in C#:

```
typedef struct _CprDeviceInfo
{
  unsigned char id[ID_LEN];
  unsigned char macAddr[MAC_LEN];
  in_addr       inAddr;
  char          ipAddr[IP_LEN];
  char          devName[INFO_NAME_LEN];
  char          port1Name[INFO_NAME_LEN];
  char          port2Name[INFO_NAME_LEN];
  int           tcpPort1;
  int           tcpPort2;
  char          interfaceIpAddr[IP_LEN];
} CprDeviceInfo, *PCprDeviceInfo;
```

The all-upper-case variables are all known constants which I can use in my C# project.

I know I must use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]`, but am not sure what the equivalent types are for each of the structure's members, and what the function signature would be when I import it. It's been a while since my C++ days.

Comment: I'd suggest to keep the structure on the VC++ side and add some calls to read the char array's one by one from c#. Using interop to transfer characters or strings with an unknown length can be hard.

Comment: There are no unknown string lengths - all lengths are defined as constants. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job for you:

```
struct CprDeviceInfo
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = ID_LEN)]
    string id;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = MAC_LEN)]
    string macAddr;
    uint inAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = IP_LEN)]
    string ipAddr;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = INFO_NAME_LEN)]
    string devName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = INFO_NAME_LEN)]
    string port1Name;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = INFO_NAME_LEN)]
    string port2Name;
    int tcpPort1;
    int tcpPort2;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = IP_LEN)]
    string interfaceIpAddr;
}
```

Make sure you are using `Charset.ASCII` in your DLLImport which is the default.

Comment: Awesome! My last question is what the signature for my function is. Is `[DllImport("CprIf.dll")] public static extern int CprFindDevices(ref CprDeviceInfo[] devices, ref int count, long timeout);` correct, or do I need to handle to pointers differently?

Comment: Your use of `long` is incorrect. That's a 64 bit integer. DWORD is always 32 bit. You should use `uint` instead.

Comment: Ah, good catch. I'd assumed a `WORD` was 32 bits, making a `DWORD` 64.

Comment: WORD is 16 bits. All these types date to windows 1.0 which was 16 bit.